# how do you add external javascript in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm learning Next.js and have spent hours trying to add external javascript.

I want to load this external script I named query.js into /pages/index.js

```
console.log("script loaded!")
function hello(){
    console.log("hello!")
}
```

The script does load when I imported the script on _app.js

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import '../public/static/query.js'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

but calling the function like this on index.js returned "ReferenceError: hello is not defined" even though the script already loaded.

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
  /* some div */
  {hello()}
  /* the rest of the code */
  )
```

what did I do wrong? I want the script to do some data processing on the browser. I have tried

Comment: you have to export "hello" from query.js

Comment: what do you want to do with hello? if you want to test only then wrap your code in useEffect which will ensure you execute on client side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it totally depends on how you plan to import your JS file.

### Your current approach

your current approach is creating a *side effect only module* which your import statement initializes- that is why you see the `console.log` statement. to make this work just attach `hello` function to the window object which is not recommended.

### Recommended approach

Usually, it's best to create modules without side effects. in that case to make this work you should `export` your function and `import` it in whatever module that you need.
here's an example:

```
console.log("script loaded!")
export function hello(){
    console.log("hello!")
}
```

and in your module

```
import {hello} from 'wherever';

export default function Home() {
  return (
  /* some div */
  {hello()}
  /* the rest of the code */
)
```

Comment: it works! thanks, do I have to import all function manually one by one or is there a way to import everything?

Comment: @namaasliku It's best to do it one by one. this way your transpiler can "tree shake" unused code which results in smaller bundle size.

Answer (score 2):

To add external javascript in Next.js you can use the `Script` component from `next/script` since v11.0.0.

Example from their website:

```
import Script from 'next/script'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Script src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js" />
    </>
  )
}
```

More info in [their official docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script).

Comment: If you use external native js library it's your choice. Worked for me.